# How to Updated Colletions Data in Client side using Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about to get updated collection records in client side means

1. All collections are there in Server Side
2. Updated or Inserted records form client side to using meteor methods server side
3. in client side show 100 records
4. **when ever modify the record or inserted not get the update record in client side**

I didn't get any idea about this.So please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically how subscriptions work. Make sure you have a subscription on the client for your collection and a matching publication on your server. Whenever the collection on the server side changes, all subscriptions in any client that should see the change, will get an update.

Comment: Other than that not possible to update?@
Thomas Goorden

Comment: Can you show some code? It's hard to tell what you are trying to do.